# Quarkus 2.0 mongodb with devServices option

Tags: mongodb, quarkus

I have quarkus2.0 application running with mongodb database.

To run my tests, I am depending on ***devServices*** option if I am not configuring quarkus.mongodb.connection-string for test profile Quarkus will start mongod docker container for tests.

Issue I have ***how to pass mongodb connection string options*** (ex: uuidRepresentation=standard). I am using uuidRepresentation=standard option for application.

Connection-String format as per below:

*mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/dbname?authSource=admin&uuidRepresentation=standard*

Comment: We don't have this capability for the time being, but it would be a nice addition. Can you open a feature request issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [property 'quarkus.mongodb.devservices.properties'](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-mongodb-client_quarkus.mongodb.devservices.properties-properties) ?

I did not try it but sound like the way to go for your use case. It's avaiable on the 2.1.0 (at least, did not check with 2.0)

Yaml configuration example:

```
"%dev":
  quarkus:
    mongodb:
      devservices:
        properties:
          uuidRepresentation: standard
```